# Animated Subviews

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uianimation

I have a split view controller in my Ipad app, in which the detail view has subviews which are UITableView's. 
The functionality I am trying to implement is to get an info view at the same position of a subview when a button(info button) on the subview is pressed. I need to get this info view by animation and that animation is that when the info button is pressed, that subview alone would flip (UIAnimationOptionFlipFromRight) and the info view would show...

This is how try to implement it -

```
-(void) showInfoView: (id)sender
{

    infoView = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewViewController" bundle:nil];
    infoView.view.frame = CGRectMake(250, 300, 200, 200);

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:1
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight 
                    animations:^{
                        [self.view addSubview:infoView.view];
                    } 
                    completion:nil];
}
```

When I run the simulator and press the info button on any subview, what happens is that the animation happens perfectly, i.e. the subview flips from the right but the infoView is not getting displayed.

It would be great if someone could tell me where I am going wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic steps of performing an animation to onscreen is as follows:

1. Create the view.
2. Move it to the initial (offscreen) position
3. Add to the view hierarchy
4. Perform the animation.

It seems like you're skipping step 3 and possibly step 2.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but I thought [self.view addSubview:infoView.view] was the way in which I add my info view.. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, but you're putting it in the wrong place. Put it before the animation call.

Comment: thanks.. I tried that out but that doesn seem to work either... I put [self.view addSubview:infoView.view] just below infoView.view.frame = CGRectMake(250, 300, 200, 200);

Comment: @learner2010 - Do you mind explaining why this answer is correct? (I'm not complaining :D, but want to clarify for future searchers, since the comments make it seem like I'm off track.)

Comment: well.. actually you are right because that is the way an animation is performed.. so that is why I accepted that answer...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the subview frame to the frame of your superview, i.e

```
 info.View.frame = self.view.frame;
```